# Creating an instance of a global variable inside $(document).ready();

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I have the following code:

```
var foo = function() {
    this.init = function() {
        alert('hiya');
    };
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    var bar = new foo();
    bar.init();
});
```

which results in:

```
Uncaught TypeError: bar.init is not a function
```

However, if I pull the new object instantiation and the .init() call out of the document.ready function, everything works as expected.

Why does jQuery's document ready not allow me to instantiate a new instance of a globally-defined function?

**Edit:** KevinB was right, foo existed elsewhere in our codebase.  I doubted that was the case as "foo" in the real-world instance is actually the unlikely-named "L8.contact_form_handler()", but apparently someone else was using that same unlikely naming scheme.

Comment: put your `foo` function inside of the `.ready` block scope.

Comment: Works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/a5e99gmp/

Comment: because *something* is overriding it.

Comment: Try `console.log(bar)` to see what it actually is.